# Help with WordPress slider

Tags: media

I Created a Theme for **Wordpress** and i created a slider.php file in inc folder . How i can call this file to show after the header .

+the slider.php file will be used to declare the slider style depending on the option in the option panel

Comment: What slider are you using? After the header where? On the entire site?

Comment: he will be just in the hompage page

Comment: What slider are you using?

Comment: idont know his nale becaus  i just found him in another theme and i want to use it in my theme but theres this word i think this is his name **flex**

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use: [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

So the only thing you have to do is put the `get_template_part` inside the `header.php` and add where you want to load it.

```
get_template_part( 'slider' );
```